# Is it safe to overload char* and std::string?

Tags: c++

I have just read about the overloading functions on a beginner book. 
Just out of curiosity I 'd like to ask whether it is safe to overload between char* and std::string.

I played with the below code and get some result. But I was not sure whether it is an undefined behavior.

```
void foo(std::string str) {
  cout << "This is the std::string version. " << endl;
}

void foo(char* str) {
  cout << "This is the char* version. " << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  foo("Hello"); // result shows char* version is invoked

  std::string s = "Hello";
  foo(s); // result shows std::string version

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Overload resolution should never cause UB that I can think of. Note that a string literal being converted to a `char *` is invalid in C++11.

Comment: @chris thanks for the advice. Then is there some explanation why `foo("Hello")` would invoke the `char *` version? My concern is that it can also invoke the `std::string` version when the `char*` was not present. Is it related to something like closeness of the types? (i.e. `"Hello"` is a literal which is closer to char* than std::string)

Comment: `const char[N]` to `char *` *was* a standard conversion, which beats out user-defined conversions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's safe, as long as you make it `const char*`, and actually often useful. String literals cannot be converted to `char*` since C++11 (and it was deprecated before that).

The `const char*` overload will be picked for a string literal because a string literal is a `const char[N]` (where `N` is the number of characters). Overloads have a kind of priority ordering over which one will be picked when multiple would work. It's considered a better match to perform array-to-pointer conversion than to construct a `std::string`.

Why can overloading `std::string` and `const char*` be useful? If you had, for example, one overload for `std::string` and one for an `bool`, the `bool` would get called when you passed a string literal. That's because the `bool` overload is still considered a better match than constructing a `std::string`. We can get around this by providing a `const char*` overload, which will beat the `bool` overload, and can just forward to the `std::string` overload.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: Perfectly safe. Consider the following uses:

```
foo("bar");//uses c string 
foo(std::string("bar") );//uses std::string
char* bar = "bar";
foo(bar);//uses c string
std::string bar_string = "bar";
foo(bar_string);//uses std::string
foo(bar_string.c_str()); //uses c string
```

Word of warning, some compilers (namely those with c++11 enabled) require the const keyword in parameter specification in order to allow temporary strings to be used.

For instance, in order to get this:
    foo("bar");
You need this:
    void foo(const char* bar);